# Got npm module: How to add bearer token to POST request

Tags: node.js, npm, node.js-got

I recently found out that `request` is no longer maintained, so the best alternative I found is `got`. I am trying to make an external API call to a REST Server but I am unsure as to how I can add a Bearer token in the authorization header of the POST request.

This is my code:

```
const response = await got.post(
  "https://${SERVER}/${SOME_ID}/conversations/${CONVERSATION_ID}/messages",
  {
    json: [
      {
        text: req.body.message,
        type: "SystemMessage",
      }
    ],
    responseType: "json",
    headers: {
        token: "Bearer pXw4BpO95OOsZiDQS7mQvOjs"
    }
  }
);
```

This results in a `401 Unauthorized`. I was unable to find direction to such implementation in the documentation provided by GOT. And since there are not a lot of queries regarding this package, I was unsuccessful in finding anything on Google as well. If anyone can help me out in this regard, that would be very helpful!

Comment: You can use they have forked the request package and it is being maintained by postman team, having all the features of request package

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that the header name is "token" ?
Usually in API, the Bearer is in a header called "Authorization"

```js
const response = await got.post(
  "https://${SERVER}/${SOME_ID}/conversations/${CONVERSATION_ID}/messages",
  {
    json: [
      {
        text: req.body.message,
        type: "SystemMessage",
      }
    ],
    responseType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer pXw4BpO95OOsZiDQS7mQvOjs"
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

`npm i postman-request` link for npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-request)

```
const request = require('postman-request');

request({
  url: 'your url',
  headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer 71D50F9987529'
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}, function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res.body);
      }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was more interested finding out how could I achieve this functionality while still using got

Comment: I gave you this way because you mention request package is deprecated but the same functionality even enhanced is being maintained by postman team in their postman-request npm package

Comment: Thanks for this. got is so poorly documented that i'm surprised anyone actually uses it.